# length of minimal projective resolution and projective dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module, representation-of-algebras

Let $K$ be a field, $A$ be a $K$-algebra, and $M$ be a finite generated $A$-module. 
How do you show that the length of a minimal projective resolution of $M$ is the projective dimension of $M$? (This statement is from *Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras. Volume 1* page 426, below the definition of injective dimension.)

> 5.7. Definition. An exact sequence
>   $$\dots \rightarrow P_m \xrightarrow{h_m} P_{m-1} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow P_1 \xrightarrow{h_1} P_0 \xrightarrow{h_0} M \rightarrow 0 $$
>   is called a **minimal projective
>   resolution** of $M$ if $h_j : P_j \rightarrow \operatorname{Im} h_j$ is a projective cover for all $j \geq 1$ and $h_0$ is a projective cover.

My thought was that given an arbitrary projective resolution
$$ 0 \rightarrow  Q_n \xrightarrow{q_n} Q_{n-1} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow Q_1 \xrightarrow{q_1} Q_0 \xrightarrow{q_0} M \rightarrow 0 $$
and a fixed minimal projective resolution
$$ 0 \rightarrow P_m \xrightarrow{p_m} P_{m-1} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow P_1 \xrightarrow{p_1} P_0 \xrightarrow{p_0} M \rightarrow 0, $$
if there exists an epimorphism $g_k: Q_k \rightarrow P_k$ for $k = 0,\dots ,m$, then $Q_k \neq 0$ for each $k$ therefore $m \leq n$, as desired. But I don't know how to prove the existence of $g_k$ when $k \geq 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to prove the following $Let 0\rightarrow Ker q_0\rightarrow Q_0\xrightarrow {q_0}M \rightarrow 0$ be short exact sequence.

let $P_0 \xrightarrow{p_0} M$ be projective cover.then there exists an epimorphism $\alpha :Q_0 \rightarrow P_0$ such that $p_0\alpha =q_0$. ($\alpha $ is epimorphism since $P_0$ is projective cover.)Hence $Ker q_0\cong Ker p_0\coprod P$ for a projective module $P$.So you can get the result.

Comment: It is true. But I tried some reasoning and still don't know how to make the process inductive. How do you show that $\operatorname{Ker} q_1 \cong \operatorname{Ker} p_1 \oplus P'$ for some projective module $P'$?

Comment: @Zelox this is easy.because $P_1\coprod P\rightarrow kerp_0\coprod P$ is projective cover.

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of Sky's answer and I write it down in case anyone need an explanation.

We only need to show that if
$\operatorname{Ker} q_n \cong \operatorname{Ker} p_n \oplus P^{(n)}$ for some projective module $P^{(n)}$, then $ \operatorname{Ker} q_{n+1} \cong \operatorname{Ker} p_{n+1} \oplus P^{(n+1)}$
for some projective module $P^{(n+1)}$.

Because $Q_{n+1} \xrightarrow{q_{n+1}} \operatorname{Ker}q_n$ is an epimorphism and 
$$P_{n+1} \oplus P^{(n)} \xrightarrow{p_{n+1}\oplus 1} \operatorname{Ker} p_n \oplus P^{(n)} \cong \operatorname{Ker}q_n$$
is a projective cover, by Lemma 17.17 from *Rings and Categories of Modules*, we have $Q_{n+1} \cong P_{n+1} \oplus P^{(n)} \oplus P^{(n+1)}$ for some projective module $P^{(n+1)}$ which is contained in $\operatorname{Ker}q_{n+1}$. An easy calculation shows that $\operatorname{Ker}q_{n+1} \cong \operatorname{Ker}(p_{n+1}\oplus 1) \oplus P^{(n+1)}$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(p_{n+1}\oplus 1) \cong \operatorname{Ker}p_{n+1}$.